# iOSOpendev failed installation - Mac 10.8.3 - Xcode 4.6.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, jailbreak

Here is the error I get: [image: http://i.imgur.com/P85OTif.png]

Any ideas? I already agreed to the license terms of xcode and that didn't solve the problem.

- Xcode version: 4.6.2
- Macintosh Version: 10.8.3
- iOSOpenDev Version: 1.6
- Error log: http://pastebin.com/Fja3cjsj

Comment: You need to provide more data. What steps have you actually accomplished up to this point? what parts were successful? Are there any irregularities with your computer (i.e. running in virtual box, or an old computer...)

Comment: Here is the full error log: http://pastebin.com/Fja3cjsj

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to menu on top bar -> Window -> Installer log (command+ L) - You will see a window will detailed installation logs where you can find out exact error.

Select "Show all logs" on top left.

Comment: This does not answer the question, and therefore does not classify as an "Answer". It is a request for clarification, and such request go in the comments of the OP.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Fja3cjsj

Comment: Hi - I had the same error 2 days back - Follow this link and you should be all set. https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev/issues/30

Comment: did it solve your issue?